# Access a dictionary at an array of keys, or initialize the key as a subdictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary (say dic) in which I want to add information about cities, so an example of an array would be:

```
lst = ["Belgium", "Flanders", "Antwerp"]
```

But this could for example be:

```
lst = ["Germany", "Berlin"]
```

i.e. the length of the array of keys at which I want to change the dictionary is unknown. Can I do something like dic[lst] to directly go down the list of subdirectories?

Ideally, whenever dic[lst] attempts to access a key which is not yet defined, it would automatically make this. This is however not necessary: I can always just check if the subdirectory exists and first initialize all of them before I navigate through my dictionary.

I would thus like to have some function f, that takes a dictionary dic, an array of keys lst and a value val. The function should return return the dictionary dic, but with val in the entry which corresponds to lst.

Comment: What is the expected output? How is the dictionary organized?

Comment: The expected output is a dictionary containing information about that city, like currency, population etc.

The dictionary is organized as follows : We take an entry for any country and then go down by a "as big as possible part of the country". This is not the same for every country (admittedly: Germany - Berlin was a poor example), but for example the city Luxembourg would be dic['Luxembourg']['Luxembourg']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for a **cascade of dictionaries**, you can use the following insertion mechanism:

```
def insert_cascade(dic,lst,val):
    for item in lst[:-1]:
        subdic = dic.get(item)
        if subdic is None:
            subdic = {}
            dic[item] = subdic
        dic = subdic
    dic[lst[-1]] = val
```

Now if we construct a `world` dictionary:

```
world = {}
```

and we insert the given sample input, we will generate:

```
>>> world = {}
>>> insert_cascade(world,["Belgium", "Flanders", "Antwerp"],'this is Antwerp')
>>> world
{'Belgium': {'Flanders': {'Antwerp': 'this is Antwerp'}}}
>>> insert_cascade(world,["Germany", "Berlin"],42)
>>> world
{'Belgium': {'Flanders': {'Antwerp': 'this is Antwerp'}}, 'Germany': {'Berlin': 42}}
```

In case we later decide to add `["Belgium", "Flanders", "Leuven"]` and `["Belgium", "Brussels","Brussels"]`, we get:

```
>>> insert_cascade(world,["Belgium", "Flanders", "Leuven"],True)
>>> world
{'Belgium': {'Flanders': {'Leuven': True, 'Antwerp': 'this is Antwerp'}}, 'Germany': {'Berlin': 42}}
>>> insert_cascade(world,["Belgium", "Brussels","Brussels"],object())
>>> world
{'Belgium': {'Brussels': {'Brussels': <object object at 0x7f90f2769080>}, 'Flanders': {'Leuven': True, 'Antwerp': 'this is Antwerp'}}, 'Germany': {'Berlin': 42}}
```

So after these insertions, our `world` consists out a dictionary with `'Belgium'` and `'Germany'` for every city, the object is assigned you pass through `val`.

Note that here you can nest the dictionary arbitrary deep. Belgium for instance has an complicated structure. So for some regions/countries, you might decide to nest deeper than for others.

Comment: This does not exactly do what I need, I need to place a value at the point where we end up and when I run your code, it just gives me an empty dictionary.

Comment: @HolyMonk: can you update the question with the problem? Together with expected output.

Comment: @HolyMonk: I've updated the answer. Does it now matches the expected behavior?

Comment: When I run your code, all it returns is an empty dictionary, in every loop you set dic = subdic, but subdic = {}?

Comment: @HolyMonk: this is done in an `if` statement, so only if the key *does not exists*. Furthermore the function does *not* return anything. It is the dictionary (`world` here) that is been updated.

Comment: @HolyMonk: the code is demonstrated in the answer. What is not working? Please edit your question with a simulation together with a case where it goes wrong.

Comment: Okay, yes you are right it does do what I want it to do! I did something wrong, sorry!
Thanks for the great answer!